# A directory independent cloud sync software?

Tags: windows, gratis, file-synchronization, cloud-storage

Is there any cloud sync software (like Dropbox) that doesn't require to put the files inside an arbitrary folder?

For me, it's annoying to always having to be limited to one single folder. It would be very useful if I could simply select the files I want, that are spread throughout my computer, and sending them to the cloud. And to sync server-computer wise, the software replaces the current files with the updated ones  all in their respective locations.

Yes, I could use hard/symbolic links, but I already do this and it's very unpractical and more of a workaround than of a real solution.

So is there a free of cost software for Windows with the same features that Dropbox has but folder independent?

Answer (score 1):

[Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/)/[Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) allows you to to choose any and multiple folders to sync.

Otherwise is very similar to dropbox but open source and self hostable.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to host it, but to publish them on someone's else servers.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to *host* a server, just *use* one, like Dropbox.

Comment: They have some [hosting partners](https://owncloud.org/hosting-partners/), but they aren't free any more.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive client [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) can do that. Just right-click any file or folder in the Windows Explorer and click "Add to Insync".

I know you asked for a free solution, unfortunately Insync is $30, but there are no running costs, so maybe this still helps.

Also note that you get a [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) pop-up every time you use this feature.